# parse patient data into HL7 ADT message format in C#

Tags: c#, .net, hl7

My requirement is parsing data into HL7 ADT message format in C#.

Please anyone suggest, I am stuck with that how to encode patient data into HL7 ADT and decode HL7 ADT message into patient data in C#.

My Model-

```
ID=2, FirstName="Harry", LastName="Dev", Email="abc@live.com", Mobile="9876543210", AlternatePhone="0123456789", Location="HA-abc, def, USA.-205", GuardianName="Test Guardian", GuardianContactNumber ="", EmergencyContactNumber="12"
```

How to encode into HL7 ADT message?

Please suggest.

Comment: I'm afraid your question in its current form is too broad to be answered here. What have you tried so far? What specific problem are you facing?

Comment: @Pieter- Thanks for replying,

Comment: But, I need parse data into HL7 ADT format, Are you familiar with HL7?

Comment: No, I'm not familiar with HL7. But if I was, I still couldn't help you unless you told me what specific problem you're dealing with.

Comment: Actually you are not familiar with HL7 so....

Comment: You may want to read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Your questions so far are very broad, which makes them difficult or very time-consuming to answer. The more specific you are, the easier it is for someone that's familiar with HL7 to help you.

Comment: @Pieter-  "parsing data into HL7 ADT message format in C#", Where you didn't understand? What is difficulties in my question, THIS IS A SIMPLE ENGLISH LANGUAGE .

Comment: @Pieter Witvoet-  Sorry, But Are you a developer/programmer ?

Comment: I understand your question, but it's too broad. Did you read up on the HL7 format? Did you look for parser libraries and try them out? Is the problem that you can't find such libraries, or that you can't get them to work, or that you don't know how to use them? Or are you trying to write your own parser? What _exactly_ is the problem you're facing?

Comment: I am trying to write my own parser, If You have worked on that then you can give me some reference that how to work with parsing into HL7 ADT.

Comment: See https://github.com/duaneedwards/nHapi/wiki/Decoding-a-message and https://github.com/duaneedwards/nHapi/wiki/Encoding-a-message

Comment: BTW - SHOUTING AT PEOPLE ISNT GOING TO HELP ONE BIT

Comment: Do you expect us to research what the HL7 standard is. You dont even provide a link to it. Even a rough description would be useful, is it binary or text, BER/ASN, XML-like, ....?

Comment: ID=2,

FirstName="Harry",

LastName="Dev",

Email="abc@live.com",

Mobile="9876543210",

AlternatePhone="0123456789",

Location="HA-abc, def, USA.-205",

GuardianName="Test Guardian",

GuardianContactNumber ="",

EmergencyContactNumber="12"

Comment: MSH|^~\&|HL7Soup|Instance1|HL7Soup|Instance2|200808181126|SECURITY|ADT^A04|MSG00001|P|2.5.1
EVN|A01-|200808181123|
PID||77291|PATID1234^9^55A||Smith^Willian^A^III||19720415|M-||2106-3|555 Upper Harbour Rd^^Springfield^NC^3401-540|NN|(919)479-4354|(919)371-654~(919)377-3455||S|AGN|PATID12345001^2^R10|1234567890|A-84334^NC
NK1|1|Smith^Barbara^K|SPO|||||20011105
NK1|1|Smith^Bill^A|FTH
PV1|1|I|2000^2012^01||||004777^LEBAUER^SIDNEY^J.|||SUR||-||1|A0-
AL1|1||^PENICILLIN||PRODUCES HIVES~RASH

Comment: i have shared my model and second is HL7 ADT demo message.

Comment: @xmojmr- This link is not useful which you shared.

Comment: @HarryDev: that's useful information to add to your question, but you still haven't told us what your actual problem is. I also need to work with unfamiliar formats and APIs from time to time, but that's not a problem, that's just part of the job. What have you tried so far, and where exactly did you get stuck? Or do you have trouble on how to get started with this?

Comment: how to get started with parsing data in HL7 ADT fomat in C# ?

Comment: @HarryDev: yes, is that what you're having trouble with?

Comment: i am simple asking that.... how to encode data in to HL7 ADT message format ? my data is below.

Comment: ID=2, FirstName="Harry", LastName="Dev", Email="abc@live.com", Mobile="9876543210", AlternatePhone="0123456789", Location="HA-abc, def, USA.-205", GuardianName="Test Guardian", GuardianContactNumber ="", EmergencyContactNumber="12"

Comment: @HarryDev: you've shown that before, but you still haven't updated your question, and you still haven't told us (in your question) what you have tried so far and where you're stuck. I'm trying to help you to improve your question so that it can be answered. Right now, you're basically asking others to do your job for you, and that's not going to work here.

Comment: @Pieter- I have edited my question. Now you can answer.

Comment: @HarryDev: your question still amounts to asking others to do your job for you. It's too broad and shows little effort from your side. We don't know what you've tried and where you're stuck _unless you tell us_, but you still haven't done that.

Answer (score 0):

"Encoding patient data into..." is beyond reach for anybody except you, unless you tell us what input format you have. "Decoding HL7 ADT" -- use parser generator to create parser for you ([Irony](https://irony.codeplex.com/), [Coco/R](http://ssw.jku.at/coco/), [GOLD](http://goldparser.org/), [LLLPG](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/664785/A-New-Parser-Generator-for-Csharp), [Roslyn](http://roslyn.codeplex.com/), [Sprache](https://github.com/sprache/sprache), or my [NLT](https://sourceforge.net/projects/naivelangtools/)). Once you start and you will have problem with the grammar, you can ask more specific question.